# Filtering in my project not working (django restframework)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filters

I'm building APIs with django and I have been trying to implement filtering into the system but the filter option just brings back all the list. Below is my codes

view.py

```
from unicodedata import name
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from rest_framework import generics, status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend
from .serializers import DailySalesSerializer, DailySalesCreateSerializer
from .models import DailySales

# Create your views here.

class DailySalesListView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = DailySalesSerializer
    queryset = DailySales.objects.all()
    name = 'Daily Sales List'
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)

    filterset_fields = ('id', 'customername','havepaid', 'datesold', 'itemsold')

    def get(self, request):
        sales = DailySales.objects.all()
        serializer = self.serializer_class(instance=sales, many=True)
        return Response(data=serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I have also added django_filters to my settings.py

Comment: I think it's because you are not using `queryset` or `get_queryset` in your get view. I see that you are making new query `sales = DailySales.objects.all()` and it's skipping filtering. You can also try using `filter_queryset` method on you custom queryset. You can read more here: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#custom-generic-filtering

Answer (score 0):

You are not using filters if you overwrite get response like that, you should change

```
sales = DailySales.objects.all()
```

to

```
sales = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
```

or even better remove your get method and inherit from `ListModelMixin` so that Django will do listing and serializing for you

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's working now